# How long does it take to measure a peak?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

Say I am measuring the position $q$ of an object in one dimension, and sampling at a rate $r$. The Fourier transform of its motion will display a peak of width $\omega$ Hz and an amplitude $A$. How long do I need to measure for in order to learn $\omega$ and $A$? And can I get an estimate of $A$ by taking a short measurement?

Answer (score 1):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle tells us that $\sigma \hat{\sigma}\geq \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $q$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ is the standard deviation of its Fourier transform, assuming that $q$ is normalized to $||q||_{L^2}=1$. So if $\hat{\sigma}$ is of order $\omega$ Hz, then ${\sigma}$ has to be at least of order $\frac{1}{4 \pi \omega}$ sec. The rate $r$ plays no direct role here, a part the fact that it needs to satisfy the Nyquist criterion.

In short, you need to measure your motion during at least $\frac{1}{4 \pi \omega}$ seconds, and you will be able to recover $\omega$ and $A$ from its Fourier transform. The shorter your measurement, the less precise will be your estimation, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for this, but two further questions:
doesn't $\sigma$ have units m s$^{-1}$? And, I can see how this would help me get an uncertainty on $\omega$, but how would I find this for A?

Comment: @Dan Goldwater Because of the normalization (the division by $||q||_{L^2}$), $\sigma$ has units $s$ (and $\hat{\sigma}$ has units $s^{-1}$). The precision of the estimation on $A$ relies on how fast the truncated Fourier transform converges, which depends on the function itself.